# Proving two parabolas containing three non-collinear points are the same

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that three non-collinear points are over only one parabola.
So I define two different parabolas and assume they are different.

$$y_{1}=a_{1}x^2+b_{1}x+c_{1}$$ and
$$y_{2}=a_{2}x^2+b_{2}x+c_{2}$$
$$y_{1}=a_{1}x^2+b_{1}+c_{1}\neq y_{2}=a_{2}x^2+b_{2}+c_{2}$$
The simplification process leaves me with:
$$x^{2}(a_{1}-a_{2})+x(b_{1}-b_{2})+c_{1}-c_2\neq 0$$
But I can't seem to find any contradiction. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Note that you haven't used your three points anywhere so far.

Comment: Three non-collinar points can fall on a circle as well. This is even more probable.

Comment: @ZAhmed What do you mean by "this is even more probable"?

Comment: The three points $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$ are not collinear, but they are not points on any parabola with the equation $y=ax^2+bx+c.$

Comment: The fact I think you want to prove is not that three non-collinear points determine a parabola (they do not in the general case where we allow the axis of the parabola to be in any direction), but that given three points with three distinct $x$ coordinates, there is a unique curve $y=ax^2+bx+c$ for constants $a,b,c$ that passes through all three points. In the case where the points are non-collinear, $a\neq0$ and the curve is a parabola.

Comment: @Ben Grossmann Oh!  I wanted to say that three non-collinear points always fall on a circle. This circle is the circumcircle of the triangle made by three such points.

Comment: @Z That I understand, but I'm not sure what exactly is supposed to be "more probable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $P_{1}(x) = a_{1}x^{2} + b_{1}x + c_{1}$ and $P_{2}(x) = a_{2}x^{2} + b_{2}x + c_{2}$.

Then $P_{1} - P_{2}$ is a polynomial function of degree at most 2, but it has three roots (since three points are on your two parabolas). Therefore $P_{1} - P_{2} = 0$.

And given three non colinear points, the existence of your parabola can be shown using Lagrange polynomial.

Comment: I am not supposed to go beyond basic linear algebra. I don´t even know what is the Lagrange polynomial and I am not supposed to use it neither.